# Magento 2.4 with AWS ES not able to install

Tags: installation, elasticsearch, magento2.4

I'm trying to install `Magento 2.4`.
I have set up `AWS ES` that I tasted and it works fine! But I keep getting an error:

```
  In SearchConfig.php line 81:

  Could not validate a connection to Elasticsearch. null
```

Is there a special configuration I need to make on AWS es?

Thank you.

Comment: are you specifying the correct credentials for elastic search in your install command line arguments? See here for more https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli.html

Comment: yes the credentials are correct.

Comment: aws access control corretcly configured? Can you manually connect from the M2 server command line with curl?

Comment: yes I can manually connect from M2 server using curl

Answer (score 2):

I actually spent the last 2 days working on this and I got it to work.
You could open AWS ES to the world and call it a day, but of course that's not safe at all.

What I have done is create a new ES domain with VPC access, no fine–grained access control and allow open access to access policy. Now you want only the servers to have access to the ES domain. Create a new Security Group giving 443 access to the Security Group that the servers are part of. By doing this you limit the access to the WEB servers and you don't need an username and password to connect.
To connect to AWS ES with username/password you need to send some headers and I am afraid Magento doesn't have this configured out of the box.

But if you decide to go with the steps above, you just need to add this to the Magento installation:

```
--elasticsearch-host="https://vpc-YOURAWSES-somerandominformation.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com" \
--elasticsearch-port=443
```

I am using port 443 because I enable to only accept HTTPS connections.

Just keep in mind that by doing this you won't have access to Kibana using public internet, as being on the VPC means it's on private network. You could create a VPN gateway and connect to it if you really want Kibana access.

Another option is to create a master user in the fine–grained access control option and use the following on the installation:

```
--elasticsearch-host="https://vpc-YOURAWSES-somerandominformation.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com" \
--elasticsearch-port=443 \
--elasticsearch-username magento \
--elasticsearch-password 'Thii$$4mePassword!'
```

As you can see I added single quotes to the password, because AWS ES needs special characters. With this setup you will be able to access Kibana.

I personally want minimum access from the world and don't care to access Kibana for the indexes. I have used Kibana/ES for Magento logs before, but I have found it to be problematic, so I just used EFS for the log folders and called it a day.

Let me know if this works out.

Comment: After almost 2 years I had the same issue with AWS OpenSearch and this is still valid. The only thing I couldn't figure out was the fine-grained access control with master user, so I decided to go without password and lock access to the servers I know need access.

Answer (score 1):

i think on aws you can connect to host `https://elk-end-point` port `443`

also you need to use latest AWS ELK `7.6+` stack

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a specific technology stack requirements that you must follow, there are PHP extensions and third-party system to install (e.g. ElasticSearch 7, MySQL 8, etc..).

You will be able to find all the [Magento 2.4 technology stack requirements](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html) in the link.

The issue that you are having is caused by the missing of the communication with ElasticSearch 7.

In order to test your ElasticSeach, you can run this command below, if needed, you can change the **localhost** to your ElasticSearch IP and port.

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/my_index/my_type/_search' -d '{
  "query" : {
    "match" : {
      "testField" : "abc"
    }
  }
}'
```