# Connect to AWS Opensearch

Tags: magento2, opensearch

I am trying to install Magento 2.4.4 using Magento CLI. I have php 8.1 installed on Amazon Linux 2.
I created AWS Opensearch and it's up and running. I can even connect via `curl`:

```
[myuser@myip html]$ curl -u 'MYUSER:MYPASSWORD' -XGET https://es-host.MYDOMAIN.com/_cluster/health
{"cluster_name":"123456789101:MY-OPENSEARCH","status":"green","timed_out":false,"number_of_nodes":1,"number_of_data_nodes":1,"discovered_master":true,"active_primary_shards":3,"active_shards":3,"relocating_shards":0,"initializing_shards":0,"unassigned_shards":0,"delayed_unassigned_shards":0,"number_of_pending_tasks":0,"number_of_in_flight_fetch":0,"task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis":0,"active_shards_percent_as_number":100.0}
```

I get a green status, 1 node and all 3 shards are running.
But when I try to install Magento I get the following error:

```
Module 'Temando_ShippingRemover':
[Progress: 656 / 1319]
[Progress: 657 / 1319]
Installing search configuration...

In SearchConfig.php line 81:

  [Magento\Framework\Validation\ValidationException]
  Could not validate a connection to Elasticsearch. No alive nodes found in your cluster


Exception trace:
  at /var/www/html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/SearchConfig.php:81
 Magento\Setup\Model\SearchConfig->validateSearchEngine() at /var/www/html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/SearchConfig.php:69
 Magento\Setup\Model\SearchConfig->saveConfiguration() at /var/www/html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php:1197
 Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->installSearchConfiguration() at n/a:n/a
 call_user_func_array() at /var/www/html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php:385
 Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->install() at /var/www/html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/InstallCommand.php:238
 Magento\Setup\Console\Command\InstallCommand->execute() at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:255
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:1009
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:273
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php:115
 Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun() at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:149
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /var/www/html/bin/magento:23
```

And this is the install command:

```
magento setup:install -vvv \
--base-url="https://MYSTORE.mydomain.com/" \
--db-host="MYSTORE.rds.amazonaws.com" \
--db-name=magento \
--db-user=MYSTOREdb \
--db-password=Thissom3StrongPassword \
--backend-frontname=securelocation \
--admin-firstname=Name \
--admin-lastname=Last \
--admin-email="MYEMAIL@gmail.com" \
--admin-user=USER \
--admin-password=Thissom3StrongPassword \
--language=en_US \
--currency=USD \
--timezone=America/Chicago \
--use-rewrites=1 \
--use-secure=0 \
--use-secure-admin=0 \
--session-save=db \
--search-engine=elasticsearch7 \
--elasticsearch-host=https://es-host.MYDOMAIN.com \
--elasticsearch-port=9200 \
--elasticsearch-enable-auth=true \
--elasticsearch-username=USERNAME \
--elasticsearch-password=PASSWORD \
--use-rewrites=1 \
--use-secure=1 \
--use-secure-admin=1
```

Magento documentation is quite useless. Does anyone have some tutorial or documentation (other than Magento) that explains?
Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have answered something similar two years ago here: [Magento 2.4 with AWS ES not able to install](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/318699/magento-2-4-with-aws-es-not-able-to-install/318861#318861)

It seems like Magento still can't connect to OpenSearch or ElasticSearch on AWS if master user is being used for authentication.

I decided to leave OpenSearch without authentication and locked down access with Security Group and allow only VPC access (no public access).

I don't need to access the dashboard, so I didn't use AWS Cognito for that, but it's an option.

Answer (score -1):

The problem that for secure connection AWS Opensearch
uses 443 port, but you specify 9200 for some reaseon.

Please fix it and all will work as expected

`--elasticsearch-port=9200` -> `--elasticsearch-port=443`

Comment: Yeah, I did that and it didn't work.
It has something to do with the password. I answered someone else when the question was about ElasticSearch: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/318861/63976

The issue continues the same, so instead of using username/password, I locked down the Security Group.